# Sending data to another page using session inside javascript and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

I have used DataTables to display data in a table and have a button to edit/add that item to be sent to another page on each row. Im trying to use ajax currently to save the data and send it to the controller but it isn't working as of right now. Im looking for a way essentially so that data that is in the console.log will be sent to the session and then I can call it on another page.

Console.log photo

[image: 1]

**car.blade.php**

```
    dataTable.on('click', '.edit', function () {
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        if ($($tr).hasClass('child')) {
            $tr = $tr.prev('.parent');
        }
        var data = dataTable.row($tr).data(); //This is the data that get put in an object/array
        console.log(data);

        $('#ccName').val(data.ccName); //puts the values in the modal
        $('#ccWeekly').val(data.ccWeekly);

        $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('car.test') }}", //tried to save the data here but it isnt working
        data: { test: $data }
        });

        $('#editForm').attr('action', '/car/'+data.ccID);
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
    });

}
```

**CarController.php**

```
function test(Request $request) {
    Session::put('data', $request->input('test') );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fix this `$data` to `data` as it is in javascript

```js
 $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('car.test') }}", //tried to save the data here but it isnt working
        data: { test: data }<-------------- HERE
     });
```

as you are getting data is `console.log(data);` from here that is JavaScript